# How to parse the image from the server and display it in the Listwidget?

Tags: qt, qt4.7

I am trying to parse the image from the server and display it in a QListWidget.

I am having the image in an array as a QString.I had tried to convert the image into QBytearray and then parse that value for displaying the image but it not works.

This is the code which i had tried:

```
 QString Image = image[i];
 QByteArray u;
  u.append(Image);

 ui->listWidget->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(QIcon(Image),Name,ui->listWidget));
```

It just displays the listwidget and not the image.When i tried using QString it displays the URL of the image and not the image.

Can anyone help me to know where i was wrong.Is there anyone any additional code to be included?

Answer (score 0):

QImage directly takes char*. So you can create an image as follows

```
int width, height; //these you have to know
QImage::Format format; //this must also be known
QImage image(Image.toAscii().data(), width, height, format);
```

I am assuming that you get info about the image from the server. If yes the above will work for you. After creating an image you can plug into the QListWidgetItem